# Adding jar from Eclipse plugin runtime tab

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to add `.jar` files for plugin from the **Runtime** tab of manifest file. When I use the **Add...** button, I can see only sub-directories of the plugin project.

So if I want to add same `.jar` file to more than one plugin project where should I store the `.jar` files.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you create a separate plugin for the jar file that exports the packages provided by the jar.  Then the other plugins depend on this.  That is how junit is handled by eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Look into creating a feature.  That way the feature can be referenced by multiple plugin.

Comment: I meant go read up on creating a feature for your shared .jar files.  It makes it easier to share .jars between plugins.  IBM has an article about writing Eclipse features (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecplug/).